# Azure Search Service Geo-replication support

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We are using Azure Search Service in our application. From documentations we know that Azure Search Service is not supporting “Geo Replication” out of the box. We want to avoid single point of failure around single instance of Azure search service. We have a couple of questions around this. Please clarify them below.

1. Is out of the box “Geo replication” feature in Azure search service is planned in future ? If yes, can you please share the ETA?
2. If we maintain at least three replicas, does it mean each instance will be deployed in different zones of same region automatically? In case, even if one zone goes down, will the requests be served by other zones without any manual intervention ?

We are finding the best way to avoid single point of failure.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unfortunately we do not currently support out of the box Geo Replication and do not have an ETA for when this will be available.
2. [Edited]: Sorry for my last response. I see that your question was about replicas spanning zones, not regions. We do make replicas automatically span zones in regions where Azure supports AZs.

We have more information on this topic here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-performance-optimization

Liam

Comment: Thanks for your response Liam. Expanding on the second point, if one zone goes down, other zones will serve the requests automatically without needing any user invention, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, the replicas are distributed across the AZ's. We have some more information on this topic here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-performance-optimization#:~:text=Availability%20Zones,-Availability%20Zones%20are&text=A%20search%20service%20runs%20within,Availability%20Zone%20within%20the%20region.